# Unable to connect to SQL Server by Soap-ui

Tags: sql-server, groovy, soapui

I want to connect to Microsoft SQL server 2012 by using SOAP-UI. I have downloaded JTDS-JDBC jar (jtds-1.3.1 Executable Jar File) and store this SoapUI-PRo-5.0.0\bin\ext folder.

Now while writing groovy code by Data Source Step, which Driver should i select.

How can I confirm that this jar file is loaded successfully when soapui is start up.

Answer (score 0):

Try `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver()` Did you see the [documentation](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#driverImplementation)?

You should see a message in the soapui log, like:

```
INFO:Adding [C:\Program Files\SmartBear\soapUI-...\bin\ext\....jar] to extensions classpath
```